# Is G/H unimodular?

Tags: group-theory, measure-theory, topological-groups

Let $G$ the group of affine linear transformation: $\phi_{g,v}(x)= gx +v$, where $g \in GL(n, \mathbb{R})$ and $v \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$. 
If $H= \{e\} \times \mathbb{R}^{n}$, then $G/H$ is unimodular? And why?

Comment: $G/H$ is just $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbf{R})$. Why define it in such an indirect way?

Comment: Thanks!!! I was not sure about it. This definition was in a example